# cannot invoke initializer for type 'item' Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to append JSON data to an array. While looping it keeps pushing an error, 'cannot invoke initializer to type 'item' with an argument of type (id: JSON, title: JSON, detail: String, ImageURL: String)'

[image]

this is how 'Item' initializer looks like:
import UIKit

```
class Item: NSObject {
    var id: String, title: String, detail: String, imageURL: String

    init(id: String, title: String, detail: String, imageURL: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.title = title
        self.detail = detail
        self.imageURL = imageURL
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your constructor expect to get `String` and you are sending `JSON`

I guess that you are using SwiftyJSON

so edit it to

```
id    : result[i]["id"].stringValue
title : result[i]["title"].stringValue
```

if you are not using SwiftJSON cast it to string

```
result[i]["id"] as! String //warning, this is not safe and better with if let
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast your objects as a certain type before initialising your object.
Try something like this.

```
var item: Item = Item(id: result[i]["id"] as! Int)
```

I'm only guessing as the value type but you get the idea. Try casting each of your values as an explicit type.